# How i can convert a string format array to array type in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string format array like

```
$string = "array(array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),array('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'))";
```

to array, and result will be :

```
echo $array[0][0];
```

---

```
  aaa
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Note that the code won't parse because you're using single quotes for encapsulating the entire string but also within the string: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'aaa' (T_STRING) in ...`

Comment: cant you just create a proper array in the first place ? what ths source of the string ?

Comment: how to get "aaa" by printing $array[0][0]

Comment: @TarekLighto see my answer below.

Comment: Dagon, i cant because i receive it from a webservice

Comment: im sure that is not the raw data returned - if you showed that we would have a much better chance of helping you- it most likely xml for json or .. what you just don't know how to process properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@cmorrissey your answer is very helpful

this is the solution:

```
    $string = '$array = array(array("aa","bb","cc","dd"),array("AA","BB","CC","DD"));';
    eval($string);
    echo $array[0][0];
```

Comment: please read all the eval warnings and relies this is just a bad idea. there are much better approaches.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that the string will always contain arrays (of any nesting) and string, you could write your own string parser to avoid `eval`ing the string.

I quickly put one together that should handle recursive arrays, strings, and numbers. It does not handle booleans, null and object instances:

```
$string = "array(array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),array('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD',1,2,3,-3.5)))";

class Tokens {
  private $tokens;
  public function __construct ($code) {
    $tokens = token_get_all("<?php " . $code . ";");
    $this->tokens = array_filter($tokens, function ($token) { 
      return (! is_array($token) || $token[0] !== T_WHITESPACE);
    });
    $this->pop();
  }
  public function pop () {
    return array_shift($this->tokens);
  }
  public function peek () {
    return $this->tokens[0];
  }
  public function doesMatch ($what) {
    $token = $this->peek();

    if (is_string($what) && ! is_array($token) && $token === $what) {
      return true;
    }
    else if (is_int($what) && is_array($token) && $token[0] === $what) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public function forceMatch ($what) {  
    $token = $this->peek();

    if (is_string($what) && (is_array($token) || $token !== $what)) {
      throw new Exception("unexpected token - expecting " . $what);
    }
    else if (is_int($what) && (! is_array($token) || $token[0] !== $what)) {
      throw new Exception("unexpected token - expecting " . token_name($what));
    }
    // consume
    $this->pop();
  }
}

function parseValue (Tokens $tokens) {
  if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_LNUMBER)) {
    // long number
    $token = $tokens->pop();
    return (int) $token[1];
  }
  if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_DNUMBER)) {
    $token = $tokens->pop();
    return (double) $token[1];
  }
  if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)) {
    $token = $tokens->pop();
    return stripslashes(substr($token[1], 1, -1));
  }

  throw new Exception("unexpected value token");
}

function parseArray (Tokens $tokens) {
  $uminus = 1;
  $found = 0;
  $result = array();

  $tokens->forceMatch(T_ARRAY);
  $tokens->forceMatch("(");

  while (true) {
    if ($tokens->doesMatch(",") && $found > 0) {
      $tokens->forceMatch(",");
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch(")")) {
      $tokens->forceMatch(")");
      break;
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch("-")) {
      $tokens->forceMatch("-");
      $uminus = -1;
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_ARRAY)) {
      $result[] = parseArray($tokens);
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_LNUMBER)) {
      // long number
      $result[] = $uminus * parseValue($tokens);
      $uminus = 1;
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_DNUMBER)) {
      // double number
      $result[] = $uminus * parseValue($tokens);
      $uminus = 1;
    }
    else if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)) {
      // string
      $string = parseValue($tokens);
      if ($tokens->doesMatch(T_DOUBLE_ARROW)) {
        $tokens->pop();
        $result[$string] = parseValue($tokens);
      }
      else {
        $result[] = $string;
      }
      $uminus = 1;
    }
    else {
      throw new Exception("yet unhandled token type");
    }

    ++$found;
  }
  return $result;
}

$tokens = new Tokens($string);
$result = parseArray($tokens);

var_dump("RESULT: ", $result);
```

I slightly more advanced version of the parser can be found in [this blog article](http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/parsing-php-arrays-with-php/).

I am not saying I'd recommend writing your own parser for this. Writing your own parser can be tricky and error-prone and should be avoided if simpler solutions are there. I just wanted to make clear that `eval` can still be avoided.

The preferred solution would probably still be to agree with the other side on a different and widely accepted format (such as JSON).

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not escaped properly, use `"` on the outside, and then `eval`

```
$string = "array(array('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'),array('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'))";

$array = eval($string);

echo $array[0][0];
```

NOTE: `eval` is dangerous when combined with user input and not available in all environments due to security issues.

Comment: I would say `eval()` is ***horrifyingly dangerous*** and is usually used to solve problems that aren't fully understood by the developer. "If `eval()` is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." -Rasmus Lerdorf, PHP BDFL [Benevolent Dictator For Life]

Comment: I'd recommend to not use that serialization format due to the problems associated with having to `eval` the data later. If your application allows it, you may rather use a format that does not require `eval`, such as JSON or PHP's `serialize` format.

Comment: error message messing end of file !!!